# React Refresh page or going back to previous url (except for the home '/' route) doesnt work

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';


const Installer = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const history = useHistory();
    return (
        <Router history={history}>>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/' component={zz} />
                        <Route path='/xx' component={xx} />
                        <Route path='/yy' component={yy} />
                    </Switch>
        </Router>
    )
}

export default Installer
```

Refreshing the page or going back doesnt work. If I manually enter url to specific page other than base url, that doesnt work either .

Answer (score 0):

I suggest instead of `useHistory()` use `goBack()`